# When using multiple inheritance, why is this qualified name ambiguous?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to access the member variable *x* in struct *Top* using a *Bottom* object.

The code is the following:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Top
{
public:
    int x = 1;
};

struct Left : public Top
{
    int x = 2;
};

struct Right : public Top
{
    int x = 3;
};

struct Bottom : public Left, public Right
{
    int x = 4;
}; 

int main()
{
    Bottom b;
    std::printf("value: %d\n", b.Left::Top::x);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the following error using gcc 4.8:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:27:45: error: 'Top' is an ambiguous base of 'Bottom'
std::printf("value: %d\n", b.Left::Top::x);
                                        ^
```

How is this ambiguous and how do I access it with a qualified name?

Comment: Both `Left` and `Right` inherit from `Top`, and both have a data member `x`. Hence the ambiguity.

Comment: it's ambiguous because you have `Left` and `Right` as subclasses of `Top`, each of which define `x`. If `Bottom` subclass both of those, then you can't determine `x` from `Left` or `Right`. For the record, your qualified name isn't ambiguous, your inheritance structure is.

Comment: I know that accessing an unqualified member of a multiple inheritance diamond is ambiguous. The question here is why is it still ambiguous if I fully qualify it. For example, if I statically cast first to Left and then to Top, I can access the correct x value. Why doesn't it work for qualified names?

Comment: Interesting - you can access through a pointer to member by writing `int Left::* ptr = &Left::Top::x;` and then accessing `b.*ptr`, but I doubt that this is the best solution. You can also write `((Left&)b).Top::x` to get it. However, I don't have a constructive answer to why the original use is ambiguous. Can you replicate this on another compiler?

Comment: I believe the way lookup for `Left::Top::x` works is "find the type `Top` in the class `Left`, then find the name `x` in the scope of that type", so it's exactly equivalent to `Top::x` (the name `Top` found in the first step being the injected-class-name).

Comment: @templatetypedef `int Left::* ptr = &Top::x;` works just fine. It's a standard pointer-to-member conversion. So does `int Left::* ptr = &Right::Top::x;`

Comment: Yes, clang 3.4 gives the same error.

Comment: @T.C. You may want to post that as an answer and give a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that C++ has no way to directly express the concept of "multiple-level" class members, such as "the member `x` of the `Top` subobject of `Left`". What `Left::Top::x` means is "the member `x` in the type denoted by `Left::Top`" - and the type denoted by `Left::Top` is exactly `Top`.

This is why you can write odd things like

```
int Left::* ptr = &Right::Top::x;
```

because the right hand side of the `=` is exactly equivalent to `&Top::x`, and a pointer-to-base-class-member is implicitly convertible to a pointer-to-derived-class-member. (The result of this conversion still refers to the member in the base-class subobject of the derived class.)

To disambiguate, you can either do something along the lines of `static_cast<Left &>(b).Top::x` or use a pointer-to-member - given `int Left::* ptr = &Top::x;`, `b.*ptr` will refer to the `x` in the `Top` subobject of the `Left` subobject of `b`.