# Do Derived1::Base and Derived2::Base refer to the same type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem, qualified-name

MSVC, Clang and GCC disagree on this code:

```
struct Base { int x; };
struct Der1 : public  Base {};
struct Der2 : public  Base {};

struct AllDer : public Der1, public Der2 {
    void foo() {
        Der1::Base::x = 5;
    }
};
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/TPBG_a)

GCC:

```
<source>: In member function 'void AllDer::foo()':    
<source>:10:21: error: 'Base' is an ambiguous base of 'AllDer'    
   10 |         Der1::Base::x = 5;    
      |                     ^    
Compiler returned: 1
```

Clang gives a similar error, and MSVC gives no error.

Who is right here?

I suppose this is covered in [[class.member.lookup]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.member.lookup), but I have difficulties understanding what it is trying to tell me for this case. Please quote the relevant parts and if possible explain in plain English.

PS: Inspired by this question [Why is Reference to Base Class ambiguous with :: -operator trough derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61476419/why-is-reference-to-base-class-ambiguous-with-operator-trough-derived-class)

PPS: Actually my doubt is whether `Der1::Base` refers to the type, that would be `Base` (and then `Der2::Base` is exactly the same type), or to the subobject. I am convinced that it is the first, but if it is the latter then MSVC would be right.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952681/when-using-multiple-inheritance-why-is-this-qualified-name-ambiguous https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648905/scope-operator-for-base-class-in-super-multiple-non-virtual-inheritance

Comment: @LanguageLawyer more good hints that gcc and clang are right, but I am not fully convinced that mscv is wrong

Comment: Obviously both refer to the same type `::Base`, but the real question seems to be slightly different here. There are two subobjects of type `Base`, and both have a `Base::x`  member.

Comment: @MSalters the PPS merely expresses my confusion. If you have a suggestion for a better title feel free to edit, I don't like it myself (because I know the answer is yes), but didn't find something more appropriate

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-base-class-in-c/

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 there is no virtual inheritance in the code (on purpose)

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 There are valid uses for non virtual, multiple identical base types, as seen in the above example. Usually virtual inheritance is used when you derive from an "interface" class (and then, not for all interface classes).

Answer (score 6):

To answer the question in the title, yes, `Derived1::Base` references the [*injected-class-name* [class.pre]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.pre#def:injected-class-name) `Base` and so does `Derived2::Base`. Both refer to the class `::Base`.

Now, if `Base` would have a *static* member `x`, then the lookup of `Base::x` would be unambiguous. There's only one.

The problem in this example is that `x` is a non-static member, and `AllDer` has *two* such members. You can disambiguate such access to `x` by specifying an **unambiguous** base class of `AllDer` which has only one `x` member. `Derived1` is an unambiguous base class, and it has one `x` member, so `Derived1::x` unambiguously specifies which of the two `x` members in `AllDer` you mean. `Base` too has only one `x` member, but it is not an unambiguous base of `AllDer`. Every instance of `AllDer` has two sub-objects of type `Base`. Therefore `Base::x` is ambiguous in your example. And since `Derived1::Base` is just another name for `Base`, this remains ambiguous.

[class.member.lookup] specifies that `x` is looked up in the context of the nested-name-specifier, so that has to be resolved first. We are indeed looking for `Base::x`, not `Derived1::x`, because we started by resolving `Derived1::Base` as `Base`. 
This part succeeds, there's only one `x` in `Base.` Note 12 in [class.member.lookup] explicitly tells you that an using an unambiguous name lookup may still fail when there are multiple subobjects with that same name. `D::i` in that example is basically your `Base::x`.

Comment: so it only "may fail" but not "must fail" and all three compilers are right? Consider for example a `template <typname A,typename B> struct foo : A,B` with some contrived code to access members of a base of `A` and `B`. In such case I want to get an error

Comment: @idclev463035818: I suspect it's a "must fail"  _diagnostic required_. In particular, this fails on 7.6.1.4/7 Class member access, "ill-formed".

Comment: I have to do a bit more reading. And I have to do some research on msvc, I suspect that some flags are needed to get fully compliant output, but have to find out which flags

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can refer to the class name as a member of the class is because cpp aliases it for convenient use, as if you wrote `using Base = ::Base;` inside Base.
The problem you’re facing is that `Der1::Base` is `Base`.
Thus, when you write `Der1::Base::x`, it’s the same as `Base::x`.

Comment: I know what is "the problem" but you are not answering my question: "Who is right? (and why?)"

Comment: @idclev463035818: I believe this is the right side. The part about `using` is written in the standard, and I think that’s the key to interpreting what the expression says.

Comment: @idclev463035818: Look at the following example. I think it will clear it up a bit. https://ideone.com/IqpXjT

Comment: sorry but I think you dont get the point of my question. I want to know what is right according to the standard, because I see different compiler do different things. Looking at what one particular compiler does to one particular example, does not help to answer the question

Comment: Just FYI, MSVC (ver 19.25.28614 for x64) fails to compile your example at [ideone.com/IqpXjT](https://ideone.com/IqpXjT). Using `cl /c /Wall /WX /Od /MDd /Za /permissive- /std:c++17 main.cpp` as its command line, I get `main.cpp(7): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'A::x'`